# Python regex for matching bb code

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a very simple bbcode parse. If i want to replace `hello i'm a [b]bold[/b] text`, i have success with replacing this regex

`r'\[b\](.*)\[\/b\]'`

with this

`<strong>\g<1></strong>`

to get `hello, i'm a <strong>bold</strong> text`.

If I have two or more tags of the same type, it fails. eg:

`i'm [b]bold[/b] and i'm [b]bold[/b] too`

gives

`i'm <strong>bold[/b] and i'm [b]bold</strong> too`

How to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: I think you forgot to close the last [b] tag in your example. So your example string should be this one: "i'm [b]bold[/b] and i'm [b]bold too[/b]" ;)

Comment: It's going to have to be very simple, since `[b][i]this[/i][/b]` use case will defeat it.

Comment: I corrected that missing `[/b]` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your regular expression from:

```
r'\[b\](.*)\[\/b\]'
```

to

```
r'\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]'
```

The `*` qualifier is greedy, appending a `?` to it you make it performing as a non-greedy qualifier.

Here's a more complete explaination taken from the python `re` documentation:

> The '*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are
>   all greedy; they match as much text as
>   possible. Sometimes this behaviour
>   isn’t desired; if the RE <.*> is
>   matched against '<H1>title</H1>', it
>   will match the entire string, and not
>   just '<H1>'. Adding '?' after the
>   qualifier makes it perform the match
>   in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as
>   few characters as possible will be
>   matched. Using .*? in the previous
>   expression will match only '<H1>'.
>
> Source: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't use regular expressions to parse non-regular languages (like matching tags).  Look into a parser instead.

Edit - a quick Google search takes me [here](http://www.willmcgugan.com/blog/tech/2007/3/10/bbcode-python-module/).

Comment: I'm new to Python.

I know this post was a long time ago, but why is it that a parser would be recommended over regex? How do the two process things differently?

Thanks

Comment: @Mike Hayes: This isn't specific to Python - it is language theory.  One simple example of why you need a parser to parse something like matching tags is the string `<b>I am nesting my <b>bold tags</b></b>`.  If you just match between pairs of `<b>` and `</b>`, you get the wrong text in this example.  To learn more, you should read about the difference between regular languages (for which you can use regular expressions) and context-free languages (for which you need a parser).